# Annotation @Transactional doesn't take effect for save opeartion in spring&hibernate project

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations

I create a simple project using spring4 + hibernate4.
I implement the CRUD functions, but I find the update operation doesn't work using annotation `@Transactional`.

If add `session.flush()`, the data can be updated.

But I have `@Transactional` in my code, why I must use `flush()`?

spring-common.xml:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cang7"></property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value="phpwind.net"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.study.user.domain</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

spring-mvc.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.study.user">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service" />
</context:component-scan>

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources location="/js/" mapping="/js/**"/>  

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

my UserDAO:

```
 @Repository
 public class UserDAO implements IUserDAO {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserDAO.class);

@Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Override
public User getUser(int id) {
    String hql = "from User u where u.userId=?";
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    query.setInteger(0, id);
    return (User) query.uniqueResult();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<User> getAllUser() {
    String hql = "from User";
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
    return query.list();
}

@Override
public void addUser(User user) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);

}

@Override
public boolean deleteUser(User user) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean updateUser(User user) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(user);
    return false;
}

 }
```

my Service:

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserService implements IUserService {

@Resource
private IUserDAO userDAO;



@Override
@Transactional
public void updateUser(User user) {
    userDAO.updateUser(user);
}

}
```

my controller:

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("/user")
 public class UserController {

@Resource(name = "userService")
private IUserService userService;

@RequestMapping("/getAllUser")
public String getAllUser(HttpServletRequest request) {

    request.setAttribute("userList", userService.getAllUser());

    return "/index";
}

@RequestMapping("/getUser")
public String getUser(int id, HttpServletRequest request) {

    request.setAttribute("user", userService.getUser(id));

    return "/editUser";
}

@RequestMapping("/toAddUser")
public String toAddUser() {
    return "/addUser";
}

@RequestMapping("addUser")
public String addUser(User user, HttpServletRequest request) {
    userService.addUser(user);
    return "redirect:/user/getAllUser";
}

@RequestMapping("updateUser")
public String updateUser(User user, HttpServletRequest request) {
    userService.updateUser(user);
    return "redirect:/user/getAllUser";
}
```

}

Comment: How is your `updateUser` method called, do you have a `hibernate.properties` or `hibernate.cfg.xml` if so post it.

Comment: Do you get `UserDAO` from a Spring context?

Comment: i have update my code, please help a look~

Comment: My "getAllUser" method can work correctly,  only "update"  can't work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966985/spring-hibernate-save-not-working

Comment: Look at this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966985/spring-hibernate-save-not-working

Comment: I have read the issue in your link, but i still don't have idea how to fix this issue in my code.   Do i need add transaction in my "updateUser" method for UserDAO?

Answer (score 0):

I have fix this issue.

The reason is that the UserService is loaded twice.
I should add in my spring-mvc.xml

```
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.study.user" >
     <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"      expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service" />
   </context:component-scan>
```